# citation in {elsarticle} worked example!

Tags: citing

Do you have any worked example showing how we cite and manage references in {elsarticle}. I already tried to use the following. It compiles successfully. Any ideas to get better form?

Here my example

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
\section{References}

\cite{Abdullah2011971}

 \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv} 
 \bibliography{science}

\end{document}
```

For example use http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877705811003481
for creating a science.bib.

Comment: How is this different from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290315/bibliography-for-elsarticle-and-use-effectively-that-in-order-to-reference-man?

Comment: @ cfr This question is trying to form several good worked examples. Look, this question has not been discussed before in a proper manner. Clear, step-by-step and address the points.

Comment: @Mohammad: Requesting `step by step` is quite bold considering the fact that you did not provide a compilable example (both here and in the other question) ;-)

Comment: Show a _complete_ example (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document} ` and the relevant entry from the `.bib` file). Without an example that reproduces the problem, we can only guess at what the issue might be. Help us to help you!

Comment: If I follow your link, click `Export` and choose `BibTeX`, I get a database entry with the name `Abdullah2011971`, but your example contains `\cite{Abdullah1965}`.

Comment: My friend, you can't just supply bits and pieces, like an `\end{document}` at the end without a `\begin{document}`. You have to provide a *complete* example. What we want is to be able to select all of the code you provide, copy and paste it and then run it. So we need everything. The code you provide should be enough to build a whole document. See [link](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Your example shows only an incorrect `.tex` file. It does not show a bibliography problem only: it will not work in any way. Complete LaTeX documents must include at least three lines: `\documentclass{<class file>}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. For a bibliography, unless the class file includes some bibliography-related stuff, you usually need to load a package like `cite`, `natbib`, or `biblatex` (among others).

Comment: That doesn't mean we'd like you to copy and paste thousands of lines of irrelevant code, we don't want your whole file, what we want is something that we can run. So you get rid of anything irrelevant and just give a basic, barebones file, which demonstrates the problem. Everything we need to answer your question, nothing that isn't directly related to your question.

Comment: @ Au101 I do agree it needs a bit more correction. Please be advised that here we are working in order to produce a worked example. The one is outlined is just a basic template. So, if you have idea you can complete that. Let us see how the result looks like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your file almost works. The main problem with it is that you use `\bibligraphy{science.bib}` so LaTeX looks for a file called `science.bib.bib`, which is probably not what you want.

The other possible problem is, as Ian Thompson noted, that you are calling for an entry that does not exist in your `.bib` file. That will fail for obvious reasons.

(Edit for greater clarity.) Assuming a `.bib` file called `science.bib` that contains the following entry:---

```
@Article{smith2000,
  author =   {Smith, A. B.},
  title =    {Title of Article},
  journal =  {Journal Title},
  year =     2000,
  volume =   22,
  pages =    {419--431}}
```

---you would construct the document in the following way:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
\section{References}

Let us have some lines (sentences) and wanted to cite references. Do I need to manually type (Abdullah 2011 et al.) etc? No, you type: 
\cite{smith2000}

If you rely on the style 'elsarticle-harv', it prescriptively determines how citations should look and normally should not be modified.

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
% not: \bibliography{science.bib}
\bibliography{science}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ jon, can you modify code for couple of references?

Comment: What would you need? It is just a matter of adding another `@article{...}`(say) to the `.bib` file, and then `\cite`-ing it in the document.

Comment: @ jon, let us have some lines (sentences) and wanted to cite references. Do I need to manually open .bib file and copy paste @article{ in the citation location in the manuscript?

Comment: @ jon, No I do not want to do this manually. You misunderstood. Look at my previous comment.

Comment: I do not understand.  The only "manual" thing you do is type the entrykey in your `.tex` file. So you type `\cite{smith2000}` or `\cite{abdullah2011}` **if** there is a corresponding entry in the `.bib` file. If the `.bib` file is empty, then you cannot `\cite` anything from it.

Comment: Remember that you must also run: `latex myfile.tex`, `bibtex myfile.aux`, `latex myfile.tex`, `latex myfile.tex` (where the project file is called `myfile.tex`). But don't "copy-and-paste" anything into the `.tex` file.

Comment: @ jon I think we almost could get to a good worked example. As far as I know we do not had such good example in forum. Thank you jon. if you feel this question is useful, please vote that.